# Electron frameless Browser Window does not completely remove entire frame/title bar on Mac

Tags: reactjs, macos, electron

I have an Electron `BrowserWindow` launched with these options:

```
const opts = {
    transparent: true,
    frame: false,
    width: 400,
    hasShadow: false,
    alwaysOnTop: true,
    resizable: false,
    titleBarStyle: "none",
    webPreferences: {
      nodeIntegration: true,
    },
  };
```

It is *almost* working as intended but there is still the top part of the frame or titlebar that is visible:

[image]

Is there any way to completely remove this?

Comment: `titleBarStyle: 'hiddenInset'` maybe?

Comment: nope unfortunately that actually shows the traffic light dots (and that darn top line still remains too)

Comment: Wait, what are you trying to do? why do a window ontop of something like this? what is the use case here?

Comment: This image is the new window. I just want to remove that top line from it that looks like a remnant of the frame or titlebar (updated to make more clear what I want to remove).

Comment: `titleBarStyle: 'hidden'` works for me

Comment: Can you provide a url where we can reproduce your issue?

Answer (score 0):

This [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=XfvpTAWQChY) contains options that seem to remove the border, but I'm honestly not sure which option removes that header line: 
`{
  width:300,
  height:300,
  movable:true,
  center:true,
  kiosk:false,
  fullscreen:false,
  frame:false,
  transparent:true
}`

Answer (score 0):

Turns out this is an issue specific to certain combinations of Electron versions and Mac OS versions.

```
titleBarStyle: 'customButtonsOnHover',
minimizable: false,
maximizable: false,
closable: false,
```

https://github.com/electron/electron/issues/15008